# How to get child element to match height of flex-grow element?

Tags: css, flexbox

I know there are tons of questions similar to mine but the complexities of flexbox are just overwhelming me. What I need seems very simple. I want the body to be equal to the height and width of the viewport. I then want everything inside to scale relative to its parents. However this is not what is happening. I have a `<div class=flex-grow-1>` and then I have a child `<div h-100>` nested inside. I would expect the height of the child to match the height of the parent. But... no. Not what is happening at all.

How do I get this image to resize to fit within the pink area? How do I get the height of this row to match the height of the pink area?

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#pink-banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #FFCFC8;
}

.title {
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size: 70px !important;
    color: #48555E;
  }

.thick-border {
    border: solid blue 5px;
}
  
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.main-text {
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #4a4a4a;
}

.text-shadow{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #b3b3b3;
  }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title></title>
      
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&family=Pacifico&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pink-banner" class="d-flex flex-column">

        <div class="shadow mb-0 pb-4 bg-light rounded-bottom header">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-0 title">Test</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="row flex-grow-1 thick-border">

            <div class="col-sm float-sm-right my-auto justify-content-center text-center">
                <h2 class="w-75 float-right main-text">
                  Words words
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm float-left-sm h-100 thick-border">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Portrait_Placeholder.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davdarobis/twh3fsoq/).

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you explain the problem uou ar having there ? I dont find a <div h-100> there in the fiddle ?

Comment: There is a `h-100` in the second "column" div. I need that image on the right to stay inside of that pink area.

Comment: Can you just check if the markup is updated ? cos i dont see it in the fiddle ?

Comment: What i see inside the second row is <div class="broken-div"></div>

Comment: Oh my I'm so sorry. I was reusing an old JSFiddle and I forgot to save this new one. It should be updated now.

Comment: Thats okay ! Check the answer I provided and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the image not getting adjusted to space you have for the parent. Give the bootstrap class - img-fluid to the img tag , and it should work fine.

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Portrait_Placeholder.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
```

See if giving it solves the problem

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. Still, thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you got bootstrap included ? It's a bootstrap class ! What's the present problem ? Did the image fit in the parent after giving the class img-fluid ?

Comment: Yes I do have bootstrap included. The problem is that the image still overflows outside of the pink area. I would like that div to be the same height as the pink area but when I put a bigger image in, it goes outside that area. Sorry I don't know if that makes any sense?